# jQuery/ Javascript : Text fade in / out

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get some text to fade in and out on a page (continuously) but I am getting compatibility problems. Here is the code I am using:

```
    function effectFadeIn(classname) { 
   $("#id").fadeOut(800).fadeIn(800, effectFadeOut(classname))
   }
   function effectFadeOut(classname) { 
     $("#id").fadeIn(800).fadeOut(800, effectFadeIn(classname)); 
    } 
 $(document).ready(function () { effectFadeIn('box');});
```

Any idea how to do this differently? Or get it to work using the above in I.E8?

Comment: Why are you chaining delay function to your custom function?

Comment: This code doesn't really make sense, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Sorry ignore the delay I was just testing. Have edited post. What am I trying to accomplish? I need to get text to fade in and out continuously on a page.

Answer (score 1):

This is surely what you want:

```
function effectFadeIn(classname) { 
   $("." + classname).fadeOut(800).fadeIn(800, function () {effectFadeOut(classname)})
}
function effectFadeOut(classname) { 
     $("." + classname).fadeIn(800).fadeOut(800, function () {effectFadeIn(classname)})); 
} 
 $(document).ready(function () { effectFadeIn('box');});
```

To call a function with arguments, you want to put it in an anonymous function.

Although there are far more code-efficient ways of doing this. But this gets your code working.

Comment: What would be a more efficient way? It must be constant, I.E not just fade in and out once.

Answer (score 0):

The FadeIn and fadeOut second parameter takes a reference to the function and will not execute it directly so what you can do is to create an anonymous function and then call the function inside that.

```
hello
```

```
 $(document).ready(function () { 
     effectFadeIn('box');              
 });

 function effectFadeIn(classname) { 
         $("."+ classname).fadeOut(800).fadeIn(800,function(){
             effectFadeOut(classname)
         });
   }
   function effectFadeOut(classname) { 
       $("."+ classname).fadeIn(800).fadeOut(800,function(){
           effectFadeIn(classname)
       }); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First hide all elements which you want to fade in.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.box').hide();
  elementFadeIn('box');
});
```

now the box starts as hidden, then it initialises the loop.

Comment: It needs to fade in and out continuously.